# tune Lenovo ThinkPad L430 to higher resolution?

Tags: resolution, thinkpad, intel-graphics

I'm using a Lenovo ThinkPad L430 notebook, its spec says, the 14 inches Screen's max resolution is 1366 x 768. the video card is Intel HD Graphics 3000.

I don't know, this 1366*768 limit, is due to Intel HD Graphics 3000 or the 14 inch screen...

Just wonder, is it possible to "overclock" (not sure if this is the correct term) it, to have a higher resolution? what's the max resolution we can get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit is usually due to the build in screen.

The physical size of the screen has nothing to due with it. There is not reason (bar expensive manufacturing) why a 14 inch screen can not be build with a much higher native resolution. That would result in a much crispier image (and more load on the GPU).

As for the Intel HD3000: It can display higher resolutions. You can confirm this yourself by plugging in an external monitor and using that. E.g. if you used a 1920x1200 monitor then the HD3000 would happily drive that.

Going back to the build in screen: Lenovo confirms that [on this page](http://www.lenovo.com/products/us/tech-specs/laptop/thinkpad/l-series/l430-l530/). Your laptop is manufactured with either a 1366 x 768 screen with 220 NITS (NITS=brightness) and a better screen which can do 1600 x 900 at 250 NITS. You selected the cheap/inferior screen.

There are two ways to get around this:

1. Switch the laptop to the model with the better screen.
2. Use an external monitor to gain a resolution [up to 2560x1600](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/quick-reference-guide-to-intel-processor-graphics/)

Comment: thanks! i'm not a hardware guy, just to check, generally, is there a way to "overclock" the screen. as CPU can be overclocked, is it possible to "overclock" a claimed 1366 x 768 resolution with 220 NITS screen so that it can display, say, 1600*900?

Comment: No. Your display can only display its native resolution. You can select a higher resolution as output but it will be scaled down. --- Maybe this will help: 1) Imagine you have a display with 1280 horizontal pixels per line. Your GPU outputs an image with 640 image elements. You now have two choices: Use half of the screen, or draw each pixel twice.  This is stretching the image to fill a higher resultion screen, and will result in a poorer image quality.  2) You can do the reverse, select a higher output and scale it down. But that will also result in poorer display quality.